# Highlight Duplicates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

There are a couple questions here on SO that are related to this, but do not help to find the answer to the question.

I have a worksheet.  Columns B3:R11 all contain names.  Within this range, I want to change the color of the test or highlight the cell of the duplicated names.  A simple google search returns several small variations of `=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1` conditional formatting.  I have tried several ways to modify this custom formula to make it work but just can't seem to get it right.

Logically, I would think it needs to be `=COUNTIF(B3:R11, B3)>1` but that does not work either.  It seems to just format random sells within the range.

How can I achieve the goal of marking duplicated cell content?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem after realizing that the conditional formating custom formula could have possibly also been iterating on not just `B3` but also the range specified `B3:R11` in the countif.  By adjusting the formula to `=COUNTIF($B3:$R11, B3)>1` so that the range was not iterated on, I was able to achieve the results I needed.